# How do I update a payload field using a regular expression

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I need to remove all non-digits from a phone number field. Since the incoming data can be in any pattern I am using a regular expression: /\D/. Since I am using version 4.2.2 and the update operator is not available I am using the update statement. The incoming payload is

```
{
  "Recipient": {
    "Name": "Bob Newhart",
    "MailingAddress": {
      "Line1": "123 Main Street",
      "Line2": "Apt 5",
      "City": "Cumming",
      "State": "GA",
      "ZipCode": "30009",
      "ZipCodePlus4": "3382"
    },
    "PhoneNumber": "(999) 555-1234",
    "Company": "Disney"
  }
}
```

My first attempt is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload.Recipient.PhoneNumber replace /\D/ with(""))
```

but that doesn't return the whole payload.

Comment: Update function is available in 4.2.2 https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dw-values-functions-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using update:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
output application/json
---
payload update ["Recipient", "PhoneNumber"] with (payload.Recipient.PhoneNumber replace /[^\d]/ with "")
```

So you already had the code necessary to produce the value you want, now you just need to use the update function (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-values-functions-update) in order to replace that field so you get the whole payload, with updated value.

Alternatively, if you were doing this without update, you could reconstruct the object liket his:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "Recipient": {
        (payload.Recipient - "PhoneNumber"),
        "PhoneNumber": payload.Recipient.PhoneNumber replace /[^\d]/ with ""
    }
}
```

Where we remove the phonenumber key from the recipient object, while expanding that object into our new recipient object, allowing us to create a new phonenumber key.

Comment: That works perfectly on my local system, so thank you! Interesting enough it throws an error in the sandbox (https://dwlang.fun/). It returns:
```You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("PhoneNumber")
  2: Name ("selector")```

Comment: Keep in mind dwlang.fun has A LOT of limitations to prevent people from crashing the shared resource. I recommend doing your testing in Studio. @CountBoxer